# Multi-line comments and new-lines

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

In C++11, the standard say in 2.2.3:

> Each comment is replaced by one space character. New-line characters are retained.

1. Is that phrase sequential, meaning retaining new-line for comment that terminates with new-line?
2. If (1) is true then why Visual C++, gcc and clang keeps empty line for each line in a multi-comment.

This questions are important because I'm writing a c++ preprocessor.

Comment: By the way, this is particularly meaningful on macro declarations, as they end on a (non-spliced) `new-line` character.

Comment: @K-ballo: even if the multi-line comment start after #define and ended after 10 lines followed by macro_name and its definition it will still work and the macro will be valid

Comment: Related: http://forum.cppgm.org/question/667/new-line-characters-in-c-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new lines it is talking about are the ones that still exist after comments are replaced by a single space character.  This is clearer when the snippet is viewed in the larger context of the paragraph it is contained in.

So specifically the new lines in multi-line comments are *not* retained, and do not terminate preprocessing directives.

Comment: if that true then what your answer for question 2?

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: They are not retaining it in the sense meant by the standard.  What is happening is that in order to print the output of the preprocessor nicely, instead of storing all non-new-line whitespace the same as a single space, they preserve some of it in their "whitespace token".  Logically however this has _no effect_ on the functionality of the preprocessor, it is just done so that the intermediate output of `gcc -E` is more human readable.

Answer (score 2):

A C/C++ preprocessor strips all comments, but generally keeps source lines at the same line numbers when you look at the preprocessor output.

This is so that a compiler which reads the preprocessor output can print correct line numbers for error messages and warnings.

Preprocessors usually also keep all empty lines as they are.

You also have to strictly differentiate between multiline macros being removed from the source and when they get expanded. They always get removed *while keeping all linefeeds*. They always get replaced with *all linefeeds stripped*. Both are totally independent operations which have nothing to do with each other.

In the old days a C preprocessor would produce its output always on stdout and the C compiler would read it from stdin. The preprocessor emits internal `#<N> "<FILE>"` statements which the C compiler interprets as 'line number N is following'. So the preprocessor could in theory do without emitting empty lines in the output. But in practice this `#<N> "<FILE>"` feature is only used for lines following `#include` statements.

Today the preprocessor is built into the C compiler for performance, but you can still look at the intermediate result if explicitly requested.

Note: See also the good comment below: The standard does not really specify how the text output of a preprocessor looks like in terms of white-spaces. The text output is implementation specific. There is quite some room for interpretation. What is defined is where at least one space character must be and that all tokes stay on their original lines (or get tagged with their original line) so that error messages make sense.

Comment: Good post, but it's important to distinguish between what the standard specifies and what is implementation-specific. The standard logical output of phase 4 is a sequence of `preprocessing-tokens` with no significant whitespace.  The "text" output format (from for example `gcc -E`) you are describing is not required or specified by the standard.  A standard-compliant preprocessor does not need to produce this format, and even if it does, it is not well-specified enough to be diff-equivalent between preprocessors.  This needs to be understood before successful comprehension of clause 16.